How to set max supply for a token using spl-token cli?
I want to create a token with the following features

Custom name and ticker
Fixed supply

The problem i am facing is that i am not able to fix the supply

If you want to fix the supply of your token, you need to disable the mint authority:
$ spl-token authorize <MINT> mint --disable

More information at https://spl.solana.com/token#example-create-a-non-fungible-token
